# Spark Scala: Vector Dataframe to RDD of values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark dataframe that has a vector in it:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [sF: vector]
```

and I'm trying to convert it to a RDD of values:

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Double, Double)]
```

However, I haven't been able to convert it properly. I've tried:

```
val m2 = m1.select($"sF").rdd.map{case Row(v1, v2) => (v1.toString.toDouble, v2.toString.toDouble)}
```

and it compiles, but I get a runtime error:

```
scala.MatchError: [[-0.1111111111111111,-0.2222222222222222]] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema)
```

when i do:

```
m2.take(10).foreach(println).
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want the first two values of the vectors present in the `sF` column, maybe this will work:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
val m2 = m1
  .select($"sF")
  .map { case Row(v: Vector) => (v(0), v(1)) }
```

You are getting an error because when you do `case Row(v1, v2)`, it will not match the contents of the rows in your DataFrame, because you are expecting two values on each row (`v1` and `v2`), but there is only one: a Vector.

Note: you don't need to call `.rdd` if you are going to do a `.map` operation.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I get an error: Any does not take parameters at the v(2) call. Any ideas why?

Comment: Is your code exactly equal to mine? Or you are omitting the `v: Vector`? The explicit `Vector` type must be there. Also, don't forget the import.

Comment: Nope, i'm including the the v: Vector part

Comment: Thanks! I needed to do the import. I was using .Vectors instead of .Vector.